# Why dropdown not working? When I click on button dropdown nothing happens

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to coding and am having an issue with a dropdown button. When I click on it, nothing happens. I don't know what I did wrong; here is my code (I tried this code in Chrome and FireFox latest versions):

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="veiwport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous"
    </head>

    <header>

    </header>

    <body>

    <div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Click
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact<li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </body>

    <footer>

    </footer>

    </html>
```

Comment: Minimum code is required.

Comment: got it found out where i did wrong i missed this part <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> i dont know what this for but when i put this code started to work .please tell me whats this for

Comment: i dont know whats for those two scripts.please tell are those necessory for the code if it so i have to memorize them

Comment: These are the CDN scripts for Jquery and Bootstrap 3. You DO NOT need jquery for Bootstrap 5 which is in your original question.

Comment: You are missing jQuery and Bootstrap JavaScript files in your HTML.  Also, under the HTML tag, the only two tags that are valid are <head> and <body>.  <header> is not a valid tag under <html>, neither is <footer>.  <header> and <footer> need to be inside the document body tags <body> and </body>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Official documentation

Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. **Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper**. Popper isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required.

And here is the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/?#overview) to documentation

You need to include popper before bootstrap.min.js at the end of the body and it will work.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the JS file that Bootstrap needs for the dropdown to work.
You can include the popper and Bootstrap separately as per Kiran's answer, or just include the bundle which combines them both into one. Paste the following script before your `body` ends.

Bootstrap Bundle JS:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Source: [Bootstrap Intro](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)